# Proper Rest API Design for Multiple Applications

Tags: php, rest

Let's say that we have an API that is being used by multiple applications from web to mobile.
I as the API developer was asked to make it restful. Thinking of being rest I would make each table on the database a model and make each of those a resource.

User can belong to many groups.

For example:

```
User Model
Group Model
Post Model
Comments Model
```

One of the needed API was a user flow.

```
# querying this one api would return all the data they asked for the flow
# which is easy for our internal developers
# but the api is also to be released publicly for outside developers
# some devs wouldn't need this
api.example.com/user/flow
```

The flow is a list of all the groups the user is a member of, with all the posts of each groups, with the comments of each post.

Initially I coded it that way, one controller to `userController@flow`.

But which would be better, above or if I'll they'd do something like:

queries:

```
# gets the data of user 1
api.example.com/user/1       

# gets the groups of user 1                    
api.example.com/group?userid=1  

# gets all the post on the groups and order everything by latest first, with initial 4 previewed comments.                 
api.example.com/posts?groupid=1,2,3,4&with=comments:4&order=desc
```

Then they will have all the post of users groups ordered by latest which is also the flow.

Which is the best way to go about?

Answer (score 0):

```
# gets the data of user 1
api.example.com/users/1
```

should also return 'groups' for user 1, so no need to have api.example.com/group?userid=1.

I'd say that every post must belong to a group/user, so basic form to get posts by user/group would be:

```
api.example.com/groups/1/posts
api.example.com/users/1/posts
```

And finally, to search in all posts:

```
api.example.com/posts?q=search+query
```

Comment: you can return array of groups for a user.

Answer (score 0):

When solving a similar problem where I had to filter a list of resources based on some condition, I came across filters in https://developers.google.com/ad-exchange/seller-rest/filters.

That is something like this:

```
pi.example.com/posts?filter=groupid == 1, groupid == 2, groupid == 3
```

I like this approach as it makes the URL cleaner and easier to understand. The OR and AND conditions are easier to achieve.